# Getting all of the orders from the last 24 hours using the SOAP API

Tags: magento-1, api, soap

This is my SOAP client code:

```
$client = new SoapClient('mybaseurl/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1');
$session = $client->login('myuser','mypass');
$filter = array('filter' => array(array('key' => 'status', 'value' => 'processing')));
$results = $client->salesOrderList($session, $filter);
```

This returns me a list of orders with the `processing` status. But I want to  get all of the orders made from the last 24 hours or 48 hours . How can i filter this ?

I tried smth like this:

```
$fromDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-1 days'));
$todayDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$filter = array('filter' => array(array('key' => 'created_tat', 'value' => array('from'=>$fromDate, 'to'=>$todayDate))));
```

But i got this message: `Array to string conversion`. Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert $fromdate and $todayDate variable format, that fetch record from order table.

```
$fromDate = date('Y-m-d'. ' 00:00:00', strtotime('-1 days'));
$todayDate = date('Y-m-d'. ' 00:00:00');
```

Then try in this way,

```
$filter = array('complex_filter'=>  array('key'=>'created_at','value'=>array('key' =>'gteq','value' => $fromDate)),
                            array('key'=>'created_at','value'=>array('key' =>'lteq','value' => $todayDate)),);

$results = $client->salesOrderList((object)array('sessionId' => $session, 'filters' => $filter));
```